# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pbrd_display_name' of undefined in reactjs and laravel application

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm getting a following error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'pbrd_display_name' of undefined**

when i try to fetch my list details by id in my reactjs application. My backend API is in Laravel. Please help

**description.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class SinglePet extends Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        SinglePet:'',
        loading:true
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/puppies/'+this.props.match.params.id)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => 
        this.setState({
            SinglePet:json.data,
            loading:false
        })    
    );
}

render() {
    let data;
    if(this.state.loading){
        data=<div className="container mt-4"><p>Loading...</p></div>
    }else{
        data=<div className="container">
                <div className="row mt-4">
                    <div className="col-4 mb-3">
                        <div className="card">
                            <img src="#" className="card-img-top" />
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h5 className="card-title">{this.state.pet.pbrd_display_name}</h5>
                                <p className="card-text">{this.state.pet.plttr_birthdate}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
    return(
        <>
            {data}
        </>
    );
    }
    }
    export default SinglePet;
```

[image: description.js page error]

please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `this.state.pet` but when you load data you put it in `this.state.SinglePet`

Comment: oh...thank you sir...